# How to dynamically add to object array?

Tags: php

So like when working with mysql_fetch_object(), how do you do things like this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $array[] = $row;
}
```

How do you accomplish that with objects instead of an array? Like,

```
$object = new stdClass;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $object[] = $row;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a lot of ugly typecasting?

Comment: That does not really make a lot of sense. What would you want the resulting object to look like?

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected outcome needs to be? Are you trying to iterate objects?

Comment: do you want to access rows like this
    $object->0->COLUMN
This is not possible. In fact it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: See my answer bellow.May be you want this.

Answer (score 2):

The first method is correct,
it should assign all the objects into `$array`,
like an array,
you can access via

```
$arr[0]->$COLUMN ...
```

I bet you are not referring to this :-

```
$object = new stdClass;
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $props = "object_{$cnt}";
     $object->$props = $row;
     ++$cnt;
}
```

The second method is assign each object into property of $object,
and you can assign the property as :-

```
 $object->object_0->$COLUMN ...
```

Comment: I know, but what if I wanted to access it with objects instead? What's the point of using mysql_fetch_object if you're just turning it into an array. EDIT: Oops, misread your post.

Comment: If you are interested, you can take a look on SPL storage for Object http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

Answer (score 0):

Other languages (like C++, C# and Java) support "generics" so you don't have to do "a lot of ugly typecasting".  PHP does't - hence the general need for a cast.

But in your case ... if "$row" starts out as an object when you put it into the array ... don't you get the same object back when you de-reference the array?

Comment: PHP arrays are about as generic as it gets, the idea of generics doesn't really apply to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$object = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $object[] = $row;
}
$object = new stdClass($object);
```

or

```
class myClass{
    private $counter = 0;
    public function add($row){
        $count = $counter++;
        $this->$count = $row;
    }
}
$object = new myClass();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $object->add($row);
}
```

or

```
class myClass implements ArrayAccess{
    private $counter = 0;
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $count = $counter++;
            $this->$count = $value;
        } else {
            $this->$offset = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->$offset);
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->$offset);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->$offset) ? $this->$offset : null;
    }
}
$object = new myClass();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
     $object[] = $row;
}
```